# Intermittent video glitches - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, kernel, graphics, video

I recently started witnessing small graphics glitches with my Ubuntu 14.04 installation which has been running fine for a while with no graphics issues. The glitches usually happen at most bottom area of the screen, but sometimes work their way up. These are intermittent flashes (lasting for only half a second or so) of black lines that happen every few minutes, depending on what I am doing.

[image]

At first I thought perhaps a bad cable, but I noticed that while playing movies in Ubuntu the problem does not happen, nor does it happen on other modes of my TV (like using my PlayStation) so I know it is not the TV set.

While I am not able to reproduce any behavior accurately that would trigger the glitches consistently, what I did notice was that the glitches were often correlated to certain mouse behavior (either scrolling in a web browser, or navigating menus and clicking on files in Unity. That being said the glitches have occurred when there is no input activity.

I tried to record the glitches with **Record My Desktop** but the glitches would not happen while that program was running, which leads me to think it is something related to either Compiz, Unity or something with the mouse.

Thinking that it might be related to Compiz, I tried `compiz --replace` with no luck. Restarting the machine hasn't changed the behavior. The only thing I can think of that changed was a system upgrade. Also, i logged into Gnome instead of Ubuntu regular and got the same glitches.

I also tried completely resetting the video with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo update-alternatives --remove gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

with no success.

Seeing now that even resetting the video configuration is not working, I am wondering what else there is to try to resolve this issue.

Running Ubuntu 64 bit on an Intel NUC 5i7RYH which has Intel Iris Graphics 6100 processor.

Comment: Have you tried the latest Intel drivers from their site?  https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0

Comment: "No support for Ubuntu 14.04 "trusty" is provided"----

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/forum/graphics-installer-discussions/do-not-use-ubuntu-14.04

Comment: Also, i havent had the need to use proprietary drivers. This system ran clean for a month with no issues, so i dont think its a driver issue. I have another clone that is a few weeks old of this install and it runs fine. Something happened Ubuntu updates.

Comment: BTW, The Intel drivers are not proprietary, they are just a newer version of the drivers that come with the system.

Comment: When you installed the system, did you install 14.04, 14.04.1, 14.04.2, or 14.04.3?

Comment: I installed 14.04 but looking at it now it says 14.04.1

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic`

Comment: This worked! excellent. .

Comment: @user4901968, if your advice worked, would you create an answer to earn your reward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic \
xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic \
libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic \
libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 \
libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

This will install the newer version of the kernel, X.org display server, and associated drivers found in Ubuntu 15.04.  These versions are installed by default when using an Ubuntu 14.04.2 or higher version CD.  For more information, see: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack