# Ubuntu 16.04 random freezes every few hours

Tags: kernel, cpu

I am using an old AIO PC with a core i5 and every few hours the pc just freezes and doesn't respond to commands, sometimes I get a message saying, `BUG: CPU#3 stuck for 23s!`

In these cases the magic SysRq keys do not work.

I am running Ubuntu Server version - 16.04 LTS

```
$ uname -r
4.7.0-040700rc3-generic

$ lspci -vnvn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [1462:ae32]
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 24
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
        Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f1ffffff
        Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
        BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
                PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller [1462:ae32]
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 34
        Region 0: Memory at f730b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
        Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [1462:ae32]
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
        Region 0: Memory at f7308000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
        Kernel modules: ehci_pci

00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [1462:ae32]
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 35
        Region 0: Memory at f7300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 25
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: f7200000-f72fffff
        Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
        BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
                PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 26
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f2100000-00000000f21fffff
        Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
        BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
                PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin D routed to IRQ 27
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: f7100000-f71fffff
        Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
        BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
                PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [1462:ae32]
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 23
        Region 0: Memory at f7307000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
        Kernel modules: ehci_pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c49] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [1462:ae32]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
        Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [1462:ae32]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 33
        Region 0: I/O ports at f070 [size=8]
        Region 1: I/O ports at f060 [size=4]
        Region 2: I/O ports at f050 [size=8]
        Region 3: I/O ports at f040 [size=4]
        Region 4: I/O ports at f020 [size=32]
        Region 5: Memory at f7306000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [1462:ae32]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 11
        Region 0: Memory at f7305000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        Region 4: I/O ports at f000 [size=32]
        Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] [10de:0df4] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] [1462:ae32]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 28
        Region 0: Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Region 1: Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Region 3: Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        Region 5: I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nouveau
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3090]
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1462:3872]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
        Region 0: Memory at f7200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
        Kernel modules: rt2800pci

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:ae32]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 29
        Region 0: I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
        Region 2: Memory at f2104000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Region 4: Memory at f2100000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169

04:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 03) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1462:ae32]
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
        Region 0: Memory at f7100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci
```

All updates are installed

What I have tried:

- Install new kernel (old = version 3.9)
- Install other distros (CentOS, Debian)
- Tried updating everything. (`sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`)
- Turning off hyper-threading

If you need any logs please say so.

Comment: Was this happening with the default kernel?

Comment: you should check this answer http://askubuntu.com/q/742278/8096

Comment: Yes this was happening on the default kernel.