# Help me find out reason of Ubuntu suddenly freezes

Tags: 22.04, freeze, system, log

So I have been using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my laptop for more than a year now, but recently I have experienced unexpected freezes or hangs. And when that happens, nothing works, not even virtual terminal. The only thing I can do is restart by the power button. I have used `journalctl -b -1 -e` to get error logs and this is the result:

```
lines 1195-1235/1235 (END)
Dec 12 21:03:13 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ google-chrome.desktop[5712]: WARNING: Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that h>
Dec 12 21:03:22 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ audit[713]: USER_AVC pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sig>
                                                                     exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:03:22 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ audit[713]: USER_AVC pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sig>
                                                                     exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:03:22 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1702393402.060:448): pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparm>
                                                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:03:22 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1702393402.060:449): pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparm>
                                                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:03:23 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ audit[713]: USER_AVC pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sig>
                                                                     exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:03:23 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ audit[713]: USER_AVC pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sig>
                                                                     exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:03:23 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1702393403.512:450): pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparm>
                                                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:03:23 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1702393403.512:451): pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparm>
                                                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:03:43 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ audit[713]: USER_AVC pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sig>
                                                                     exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:03:43 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ audit[713]: USER_AVC pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sig>
                                                                     exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:03:43 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1702393423.408:452): pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparm>
                                                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:03:43 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1702393423.408:453): pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparm>
                                                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:05:00 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ audit[713]: USER_AVC pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sig>
                                                                     exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:05:00 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1702393500.861:454): pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparm>
                                                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:05:00 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ audit[713]: USER_AVC pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sig>
                                                                     exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:05:00 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1702393500.865:455): pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparm>
                                                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:05:13 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ audit[713]: USER_AVC pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sig>
                                                                     exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:05:13 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1702393513.317:456): pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparm>
                                                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:05:13 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1702393513.321:457): pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparm>
                                                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 12 21:05:13 imran-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509DJ-D509DJ audit[713]: USER_AVC pid=713 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sig>
                                                                     exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

Some assistance will be greatly appreciated about what I should do now.

Also here are my PC specs should that provide any info:

Ryzen 5 3500U
Ram: 12GB
256GB SSD, 1TB HDD

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: So this is my swap size ```11144588``` but used ```0```, so they are all free. And I checked the swappiness to be ```60```.

Comment: Have you tried a memtest86 to check if your memory has developed a fault? Seems a bit strange that it's only started recently. In addition to the already mentioned commands, the `htop` command can be used for realtime monitoring of resource use

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diagnosing and fixing random Ubuntu crashes without SysReq?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742278/diagnosing-and-fixing-random-ubuntu-crashes-without-sysreq)